# Which executes first postback or jquery event

Tags: jquery, asp.net, events, postback

I have a button which retrieves in codebehind some value from Database . The button itself
has a click event handled by Jquery . The problem is I need to use the retrieved value
from database in the jquery click action .

So, Is that possible ?

Comment: If your AJAX call is inside the click function, then once a response is retrieved you can use that throughout the rest of the click function (if this is what you're asking).

Comment: You can call a JavaScript function after server PostBack gets over: `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(pg, Me.GetType(), "PostBack", "jsFunctionName();", True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's not possible.**

The events bound via jQuery will get executed first, only after that the page is posted back.

You may have to use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to get *value* from your server.

Or

You can store your *value* in a hiddenfield from code behind,and in your javascript code...

```
$(function(){
   if($("#hiddenfieldID").val())
   {
    //transfer control to wherever you want
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling ajax method will not wait for the response, so the function in click() even will quit before you receive the response from server. But you can refactor your code a bit to get the job done:

```
$button.click(function(){
   $.get('your-url', function(dataFromDb){
      // do something with dataFromDb
      alert('Got the response from server!');
   });
});
```